# Preparing a special exam sheet for every student

Tags: loops, excel

I am wondering if there is a way to read the data from an excel file and then somehow using a forloop outside a tabular, get a special exam sheet for each student.

Until now, we have been using a code similar to this one:

```
Fill the blanks below and answer the question.

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Name:    & E-mail:         \\ \hline
Surname: & Student Number: \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

Question: 2+2=?
```

and we print the above paper 100 times for a class of 100 student. Now I want to do something like this:

```
\readfile{students.xls}

\forloop{from i=1 to i=100}{

Answer the question below.

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Name: \cell{A_i}    & E-mail: \cell{B_i}         \\ \hline
Surname: \cell{C_i} & Student Number: \cell{D_i} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

Question: 2+2=?

\newpage
}
```

to get a 100-page .pdf file in which every student has a special page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never used it but I think this should be possible with the `datatool` package and a csv file (you can export your excel file into a csv format)

Comment: I normally do that the other way around, by using a python script that generates a LaTeX source. If you are interested, http://rlog.rgtti.com/software/python/python-and-openoffice/

Comment: Would love to see this expanded - Often teachers have to produce 3 versions of the same test - easy/medium/hard - using different question pools and some students only having 3 choices instead of 4.  Scripting the test in python or LuaTex seems like a good option if there was a nice template to start from.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [odsfile](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/odsfile) package, which supports manipulations with OpenDocument Spreadsheet files. You need to convert your excel file to ODS using LibreOffice (Excel can do this as well, but LibreOffice produces cleaner files).

`Odsfile` provides `\includespread` command with keyval interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{odsfile}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\includespread[%
  file=students.ods,
  range=a1:d,
  rowtemplate={%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}%
    \hline%
    Name: -{1} & E-mail: -{2}\\ \hline% 
    Surname: -{3} & Student Number: -{4}\\ \hline%
    \end{tabular}%
  \endgraf%
    Question: $2 + 2  = $ ?
    \newpage},
  ]

\end{document}
```

`file` property specifies spreadsheet file, range specifies range to be processed (columns are `a`, `b`, `c`, etc., rows are numbered, default value for second part of the range is row count, when the number is left).

`rowtemplate` enables to specify code which will be executed for each row, columns are accessed using `-{column number}`. Note that we must use `\endgraf` instead of paragraphs.

The file must be compiled using `lualatex`.

Sample:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer**: You are looking for Auto Multiple Choice ([AMC](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/)).

**Long answer**: You are looking for Auto Multiple Choice ([AMC](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/)) that is a LaTeX package and a free GUI  program for Linux. If you are a Window user that make regularly exams, it worth to install Linux only to have this program. AMC can make one exam to each student with randomly questions, so each student have completely different questions, or alternatively the same questions, but randomly mixed, with answers in different order too.  The scanned images of the written exams may be marked automatically, and their results exported to a LibreOffice spreadsheet linked to the student names using some identification code.

Comment: Off topic: Linux users, be careful when trying to install it from terminal, because it will ask to install texlive from repository and a lot of other TeX stuffs.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for the same question on all 100 tests, with header information student specific. Nevertheless this answer may help others who find their way here.

Comment: @Siguir This will happen installing any program with dependencies with texlive  (Gummi, Latexila, etc.). See [Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) to a solution to this.

Comment: @EthanBolker ACM is designed to scan a ID code and /or the signature to respectively assign automatically and/or  manually the sheet evaluation to the student name. Moreover the exam copies are numbered, making nominative sheets needless. But AMC can also will print the students names from a CSV file so you do not need a student ID. See [here](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/auto-multiple-choice.en/ar01s07.shtml#idp6443792).

Comment: off-topic, but I do not recommend nominative sheets in general, at least without additional signature, because then is impossible  verify the real identity of the student a posteriori (The exam with name A was really made by the the student A ... or may be someone else?)   Even not malicious exchange of exams is possible when the  students are not forced to  write thir own name in their own handwriting!

Answer (score 2):

you can use csvsimple package (http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf)

Here are some possibilities of this package that I find very useful. Documentation is very detailed

with the given data file

================ StudentFile.txt============

```
name, email, surname, studentnumber
robert, robert@yahoo.fr, roro, 123466
julie, juju@gmail.com, juju, 987456
laure,lolo@test.fr,lolo, 147852
aline,lili@us.com,lili,963258
martine,mart@hotmail.com, titine,258741
```

===========================================

and latex source

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvreader%
{StudentFile.txt}{1=\name,2=\email,3=\surname,4=\studentnumber}%
{
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Name: \name   & E-mail: \email       \\ \hline
Surname: \surname & Student Number: \studentnumber \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vfill
Questions:

$2+\studentnumber=????$
\vfill
\clearpage
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the page numbers? it is giving running page numbers. But each question paper should have its own page numbers know?

Comment: use \pagestyle{empty}

Comment: no actually, suppose  the questionaire is having 5 pages and I want the page numbers for the 5 pages not for the whole pdf files..@rpapa

Answer (score 1):

A poor man low weight no package approach, limited to four records (could go to nine records if space removal was handled more seriously). To be adapted to one's needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
% only for self-contained example here
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{StudentFile.txt}
robert, robert@yahoo.fr, roro, 123466
julie, juju@gmail.com, juju, 987456
laure,lolo@test.fr,lolo, 147852
aline,lili@us.com,lili,963258
martine,mart@hotmail.com, titine,258741
\end{filecontents*}

% input stream
\newread\MyFile

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ParseCSVFile [1]{%
    \openin\MyFile #1\relax
    {\endlinechar-1\ParseCSVFile@}%
    \closein\MyFile
}%
\def\ParseCSVFile@ {%
    \ifeof \MyFile
    \else
        \read \MyFile to \ParseCSVFile@oneline
%debugging
%\typeout{ICI: \ParseCSVFile@oneline}%
        \ifx\ParseCSVFile@oneline\par
        \else
        \ifx\ParseCSVFile@oneline\empty
        \else
           \expandafter
               \ParseCSVFile@DoOneLine\ParseCSVFile@oneline$$$$%
        \fi\fi
        \expandafter\ParseCSVFile@
    \fi
}%

% to be customized as need. 
\def\ParseCSVFile@DoOneLine #1#2,#3#4,#5#6,#7#8$$$${%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}%
    \hline
    Name: #1#2& E-mail: #3#4\\ 
    \hline
    Surname: #5#6& Student Number: #7#8\\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \par
    Question: $2 + 2  = $ ?
\clearpage
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ParseCSVFile {StudentFile.txt}

\end{document}
```